# How to filter data in MongoDB where count greater than one?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to retrieve records from contacts array whose `ContactGroup` does not have `Club`, i.e for the below data I shall get only object with `ContactName` as Ravi.

[Data in MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4Zzy.png)

[image]

**The below is my query (on Mongo DB M0)**

```
db.phonenumbers.aggregate(
[{$match:{"userName" : "Veer"}}, 
{$unwind : "$contacts"},
{$unwind : "$contacts.ContactGroup"},
{$match:{"contacts.ContactGroup":{$ne:"Club"}}},
{$project : { "contacts.ContactName":1,"contacts.ContactGroup":1,_id : 0}}
])
```

Notice the **Result**, I am supposed to get only Ravi but I get others too.

Please advice how I can fix the query ?

```
{ contacts: { ContactName: 'Ravi', ContactGroup: 'Family' } }
{ contacts: { ContactName: 'Ravi', ContactGroup: 'Business' } }
{ contacts: { ContactName: 'Ram', ContactGroup: 'Friends' } }
{ contacts: { ContactName: 'Santosh', ContactGroup: 'Business' } }
```

Comment: Did you try matching before the second `$unwind`?

Answer (score 0):

You are **unwinding** `contacts.ContactGroup` and then **matching** by it. Try to reverse the order of these actions. That will filter out all objects that does not have **"Club"** value in the `ContactGroup` array.

```
db.phonenumbers.aggregate([
  { $match:{"userName" : "Veer"} }, 
  { $unwind : "$contacts" },
  { $match:{"contacts.ContactGroup":{$ne:"Club"}} },
  { $unwind : "$contacts.ContactGroup" },
  { $project : { "contacts.ContactName":1,"contacts.ContactGroup":1,_id : 0} }
])
```

Comment: Welcome. Consider upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you.